# Java application goes to nowhere - Am I having a versioning issue?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am having the following, very simple code in a Java application which I am running under Tomcat 7 and OpenJDK Java 1.7

```
List<AnnotationNode> children = parent.getChildren();

LOGGER.debug("sorting ...");

children.sort(new Comparator<AnnotationNode>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(AnnotationNode o1, AnnotationNode o2) {

        int result;
        try {
            Annotation a1 = o1.getAnnotation();
            Annotation a2 = o2.getAnnotation();             
            LOGGER.debug("compare ..");
            result  = a1.getStart() - a2.getStart();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug("huh??", e);
            result =0;
        }

        return result;
    }           
});
```

Please excuse those `LOGGER` messages but it was the only way for me to track down the origin of the problem. As I am executing a GET request, the program simply goes into no mans land and the request is getting swallowed.

I've started Tomcat in debug mode in order to remote debug the application from my Eclipse. The result is that it reaches `.sort()` but it will never reach my implementation of `compare()`. So the last debug message I am receiving is `sorting ...` and that's it.

The machine I am deploying this from has Java 8 installed

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

but the parent pom.xml is set for Java 7:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This looks like I'm having an issue with Java versions here although I am not sure where this problem occurs. Is it possible that my application is getting built with the wrong compiler here?

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

---

**Update:**

The last message in `/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out` says:

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V
    at at.company.enrichment.processor.AnnotatedDocumentTree.addNode(AnnotatedDocumentTree.java:104)
    at at.company.enrichment.processor.AnnotatedDocumentTree.initialize(AnnotatedDocumentTree.java:70)
    at at.company.enrichment.processor.AnnotatedDocumentTree.<init>(AnnotatedDocumentTree.java:41)
    at at.company.enrichment.processor.DocumentProcessor2.process(DocumentProcessor2.java:112)
```

Why am I getting a `NoSuchMethodError` exception here?

Comment: "...goes into no mans land" - does that mean you are running into a timeout? How big is that list?

Comment: @Fildor The list is rather small so it's definitely not that it's just taking too long.

Comment: Have you tried putting a LOG before calling `.getAnnotation()` in the comparer? Just to make sure it is not that method that is "hanging" and the comparer code is actually entered.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, did that too. I've just updated my question - it appears that I am getting a `NoSuchMethodError` exception ..

Comment: Try using [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). `List` indeed does not have a `sort` method according to JavaDocs in Java 7.

Comment: You need to start tomcat with Java 8 to have the List#sort() method. Or you rewrite it to Collections.sort(children, comp); which exists with Java 7

Comment: @eckes That was it. Changing it to `Collections.sort()` worked. What a tricky error.

Comment: @eckes If you provide an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List#sort(Comparator)` method is new in Java 8. If your Tomcat works with Java 7 it will not find the method. What you can do is to use the Java 7 version `Collections#sort(Collection, Comparator)` which exists in Java 7 and Java 8.

Generally speaking it is better to compile your code with the same Java version you intend to run it. In that case the compiler will give you the error, not the runtime.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a missing dependency on a library you are using (are you using ASM?), when deploying the web application on tomcat.

To be more precise I would need to see complete logs of tomcat and imports of your class.

Comment: What library could that be? This is just `List#sort` what I am calling - but where can I get the logs of tomcat?

Comment: actually you are using AnnotationNode and Annotation in your sort method, so if the classloader fails loading these classes, it could explain the timeout

Comment: tomcat logs: try in /var/log/tomcat (if using linux)

Comment: Got it - it appears that I am getting a `NoSuchMethodError` - any idea why this might be the case? This looks odd to me ..

Comment: or in the home directory of tomcat, there is a log directory; lookup catalina.out file

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: referred to which method? can you post the complete message?

Comment: I've added it to my question.